# Open a modal with a text area to fill and a text area loading some content from the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working with WebForms and I need to create a modal, or anything like this on click on a button to reject an item, the modal should show the item ID and a text area to fill up with the reason why this item will be rejected.

I'm on it for about one week and I can't figure out how could I get the item id and put it on the modal.

I've never used WebForms before, and I'm not finding anything that helps me.

this is my modal code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMotivoRejeitarTitulo" runat="server" Width="610px">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowModalPopup2" Style="display: none" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalRejeitarTitulo" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowModalPopup2"
                PopupControlID="divPopUp2" BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle"
                DropShadow="true" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" />
            <div class="popUpStyle" id="divPopUp2" style="display: none;">
                <div style="width: 600px; max-height: 160px;">
                    <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="panel1" CssClass="drag01">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTituloModal" runat="server" Text="EXCLUIR TÍTULO?"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <div class="subtitulo">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMensagemOrigemAgregadoMiudo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlRejeitarTitulo" runat="server" Width="550px" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
                        CssClass="centralizaPanel" BorderStyle="Outset">
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <div class="campo">
                                <div class="label_formulario8">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="ID: "></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="campo">
                                <div class="label_formulario8">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Descrição: "></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescricao" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="centraliza_botao">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmarExcluirTitulo" runat="server" Text="Confirmar" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnConfirmarExcluirTitulo_Click"
                                Style="height: 31px" CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnFecharExcluirTitulo" runat="server" Text="Fechar" CssClass="btn btn-warning"
                                Style="height: 31px" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnFecharExcluirTitulo_Click" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

on txtId must appear the item ID, I've tried to use JS getting the id of the rendered input, but it take so long to render, so JS does not work.

Comment: Which control has the ID you need to display in the modal?

Comment: The ID is "modalRejeitarTitulo" but I have found a way to open it correctly, thank you for your time to come here to help me!

I realized that I was using this feature of the system in the wrong way. So when I discovered how to use it, the modal shows up correctly. I'm embaressed right now because of this, I'm a newbie in this architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had to fill all the fields before call the method that shows the modal dialog.

I was thinking like jQuery but it does work like that on WebForms